# list elements not inheriting styles from parents

Tags: html, css

Any idea why 'li' elements are not inheriting 'p' elements style in the following snippets?
i.e 'role1' and 'role2' are rendering as black while 'Hello world!' and 'Inside nested p' are in blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        p {
            color: blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello World !
            <ol>
                <li>role1</li>
                <li>role2</li>
            </ol>
            <p>
                Inside nested p
            </p>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: change your style description to make list elements rendering blue. check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p tag can not contain block level elements.
So the browser automaticaly closes the p tag for you.
Your html will parse like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        p {
            color: blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Hello World !
        </p>
            <ol>
                <li>role1</li>
                <li>role2</li>
            </ol>
            <p>
                Inside nested p
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now you see why Hello world and Inside nested p are blue and the li elements are not

Answer (score 3):

Ya, Rick Hoving is correct. If you want to apply blue color to all p and ol or what ever. You need to put this in to div block/container as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        div {
            color: blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <p>
            Hello World !
            <ol>
                <li>role1</li>
                <li>role2</li>
            </ol>
            <p>
                Inside nested p
            </p>
        </p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using your own custom tags or classes in style description:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        custom {
            color: blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <custom>
            Hello World !
            <ol>
                <li>role1</li>
                <li>role2</li>
            </ol>
            <p>
                Inside nested p
            </p>
        </custom>
    </body>
</html>
```